# .so is not a valid ELF object

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-ndk

Hi in my Android project I need to access some `C++` code so I created shared library project on
`Linux` and generated `.so` file .

Now when I put this `.so` file inside `libs/armeabi` folder in my Android project and I load that `.so` file via code as

```
System.loadLibrary("name of so file without prefix lib and extention .so");
```

I am getting

```
12-30 17:01:12.628: E/AndroidRuntime(6472): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: get_lib_extents[758]:   104 - /data/data/com.example.demo/lib/libextractimage.so is not a valid ELF object
```

Now I dont know why I am getting this issue and where is the problem

Please help me.

Comment: Is the library correctly cross-compiled to the target platform?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am not more familier with Linux but I have created project on Linux 64 bit system and when I have build the application in release mode then .so is getting generated in release folder that I have copied to my libs folder

Comment: my eclipse is also for 64 bit system

Comment: The host of your build system is not the same as the target system. Your host is an x86_64 system, the target system is a ARM system. Different CPUs and instruction sets is just the beginning of your problem.

Comment: so what can I do to resolve this . please help

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how can i cross compile it so that i can use this .so file

Comment: you need a cross-compiler on your pc. just search `build a cross compiler` on google, you will get a full list of answer.

Comment: You should build the library using the Android NDK.

Comment: @Michael I never worked with JNI and NDK . If you know how to build  C++ shared library project using android ndk so that I can use .so file in my android project plz can u share some hint

Comment: The NDK includes several example projects, so you can look at them to get an idea of how to set things up.

Comment: @Michael my c++ project has seveval dependencies . but while reading thorugh NDK, i read we need to put native.c file in jni folder so how it will get reference to other dependencies.

Comment: By adding them as additional modules in your Android.mk file. Either as shared/static libraries, or as prebuilt shared/static libraries.

Comment: my C++ project has .h files, multiple .CPP files and also has other dependencies from local system has been added so how and where i need to put.